# Is it possible to make Datasources for SFTP in Wildfly 16 or any alternative to do that?

Tags: server, wildfly, sftp, wildfly-16

We have a SFTP server which is accessed in 50 integrations.

We need to configure SFTP in properties file for all integrations. 
is it possible to configure the same inside wildfly server itself so that we can use it like

```
@Resource(name="java:bla/bla/bla")
DataSource mdDb
```

Comment: You could implement a resource adapter you could then assign to a JNDI path in the resource-adapters subsystem.

Comment: @Aaron: Thanks. Any idea how can we configure SFTP there as when i try to add it says archive, module and name. Online i am not able to find sftp example. Found one article but not straight forward: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Resource+adapters

Comment: You can check Oracle documentation on how to build a resource adapter, you'll need code but it should be close to what you're using in your 50 services using FTP.